# Getting exception in gradle while building java project

Tags: java, gradle

I'm working with gradle and quit new in using it.I've installed its latest version form their website and following gradle's official tutorails for getting started. But having problem in building java project. I've searched but couldn't find any usefull solution. When I run 'gradle build' it is supposed to build the java project on root directory but it gives following error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
org/gradle/internal/service/scopes/PluginServiceRegistry
```

The build file configurations are:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'
jar {
manifest {
    attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
               'Implementation-Version': version
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version:               '3.2'
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}

test {
systemProperties 'property': 'value'
}

uploadArchives {
repositories {
   flatDir {
       dirs 'repos'
   }
}
}
```

The Stacktrace for exception is

```
* Exception is:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/internal/service/scopes/PluginService
Registry
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceLocator.findServiceImplementations
(ServiceLocator.java:109)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceLocator.findFactoriesForServiceTyp
e(ServiceLocator.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceLocator.getAll(ServiceLocator.java
:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.GlobalScopeServices.configure(Glob
alScopeServices.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.invoke(DefaultServ
iceRegistry.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.findConfigureMetho
d(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:149)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.findProviderMethod
s(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:119)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.addProvider(Defaul
tServiceRegistry.java:227)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder.build(ServiceRegis
tryBuilder.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.BuildActionsFactory.runBuildInProcess(BuildAc
tionsFactory.java:159)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.BuildActionsFactory.createAction(BuildActions
Factory.java:133)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.
createAction(CommandLineActionFactory.java:242)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.
execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:232)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.
execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRunti
meValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRunti
meValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(
CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(
CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRep
ortingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRep
ortingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBoots
trap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.j
ava:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.
PluginServiceRegistry
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 47 more
```

My jdk version is 1.8.0 and gradle version is 2.2.1.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please paste the entire error that you're getting. Also, at what directory level is the `gradle build` command being executed?

Comment: I'm running gradle on 'C:\gradle-2.2.1\bin>' and entire error is 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
org/gradle/internal/service/scopes/PluginServiceRegistry
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

Comment: please run with --stacktrace and paste the stacktrace here

Comment: @ReneGroeschke I've Updated the question with stacktrace exception message.

Comment: your build script looks good to me. Not sure what happened here. could you provide more details about the environment you're running gradle in. does gradle --version works for you? Somehow it feels like the distribution you use is invalid and probably misses some jars!?

Comment: I'm using jdk 1.8.0 and gradle version is 2.2.1.